# Can someone please tell how to use find command to check if logfiles are updates with timestamp?

Tags: bash, shell-script

*Can someone please tell me how do I use find command to make sure the serverlogs with timestamp are updated daily*

```
server.log.2020-11-02
server.log.2020-11-01
server.log.2020-10-31
server.log.2020-10-30
```

The path of the log files is /home/usr/logs/server.log.2020-xx-xx

Comment: I only want to check the existence of the file ,want to make sure daily it is updated

Comment: I am looking if there is any parameter of find that would help me determine ,how old the file is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if the server.log is updated everyday?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622702/how-do-i-check-if-the-server-log-is-updated-everyday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check daily if this command failes
`file server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`

or something like:
`[ -f server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d) ] && echo ok || echo not`

Comment: and you can check the status of the file with `stat -f  server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`        read more about stat options, it might help you find what you are looking for.